# Normal map bakes with transparent areas

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, texture-baking

I have been trying to bake my high-poly mesh to low-poly mesh but I'm getting a transparent image after baking.

[image: screenshot with settings]

[image: baked result]

My normals are in the right direction. I'm using blender 2.93.

Can u guys fix the error??
I am attaching the link of my project the baked image is attached in with the project.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RgUyz3G9af0h_j1DqAVmz-XAqwOsAC_0/view?usp=sharing

Thank you in advance!

Comment: it works here, make sure that you're looking at the right picture, according to your node setup the one that will receive the bake is called NORMAL

Comment: @moonboots. M getting the same bake  image as the image attached in the project file.

Comment: @if its ok can u upload the baked file

Comment: How have you baked this to get the transparency? I've tried it with 2 new images, one with an Alpha channel, one without. The baked images are both fine. There is no transparency. Used Blender 2.92, increased Extrusion to 0.15 m, and lowered the Subdivision Surface modifier on the low-poly object from 3 to 1.

Comment: Here is the baked result, there are still some glitches: https://pasteall.org/pic/03b9e56f7dce45c1abfdba2ff4bef1c0

Comment: @blunder, Hi i have tried the same settings mentioned still i got the transparent image as per setting you have mentioned.One exception i have is m using blender 2.93 may thts the bug.anyways m attaching my setting and baked image once again.  image:[link](https://pasteall.org/pic/e4f5ba8d743d4180bddb72d8d88a2e09) setting:[link](https://pasteall.org/pic/e000a0dfd05440a6a774fe4193be4700)

Comment: There is something wrong. I can try Blender 2.93 later. Have you tried to use a new image without an alpha channel/transparency? Just uncheck the *Alpha* checkbox in the new image dialog to do this.

Comment: @ Nilesh Janghel, here is my try: https://zupimages.net/up/21/23/0vyf.png

Comment: @Blunder , There is something worng with 2.93 ,even i did the same with 2.92 and got the baked image,please try once with 2.93 once amd tell me, here is the image without alpha checkbox -[link](https://pasteall.org/pic/65788b82c437400f897960ea2415233e)

Comment: @moonboots, which version of blender did you used??

Comment: it's 2.93, the latest, it works fine with 2.92 as well, can it be a problem with your graphic card driver?

Comment: I've just tried Blender 2.93 (win64), created an image like yours, 4k with Alpha. The result looks fine, like moonboots' image. But I bake with the CPU. GPU is greyed-out. Maybe it's your GPU or the graphic card driver. In the Cycles settings, switch GPU to CPU and give it a try.

Comment: @Blunder  Thank you guys,i fixed the error it was related to my hardware i.e my HDD was causing the issue i moved my files to my SSD,the issue was solved thank you anyways!!

Comment: @moonboots     Thank You!!