# Failing to bake material into a texture

Tags: materials, shaders, texture-baking, artifacts

So I want to convert my material into a texture for exportation.

Following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v7vdpiPV-3E) while referencing a lot of others including other posts here. I believe I understand what to do. Switch to *cycles*, scroll down to *bake* set bake type to *diffuse* and then only select colour. Have a vacant image node with a new texture set up but I only get this;

[image]

This is my node tree:
[image]

And this is the associated model:
[image]

Is this because I'm using emission nodes? I see in the combined bake type there is a *emit* check box but I've had no luck with this.

Thanks for your help and have a good day! :)

Comment: Why is the hoodie black on screenshot 2? - *"Is this because I'm using emission nodes?"* No, it should bake the output of the BSDF with lightning and shadows if the options are selected. But you could give it a try. Replace the BSDF with an *Emission* node and select *Bake Type = Emit*. If it doesn't work something else is wrong. Blender sometimes has an update glitch. Make sure you save the baked image and have a look at the saved file, or use *Image>Reload* in Blender.

Comment: Also on your screenshot the Image Texture node with is not selected, and I believe it has to be.

Comment: I don't think that selecting the Image Texture Node is important because it's already set up to that texture and it didn't make a difference. I also tried using a diffuse shader and an emission shader with the combined bake type. The hoodie is also that dark intentionally. It's meant to be a black hoodie but I keep getting a pure white bake that fits how it was originally unwrapped. I don't know if you have any other ideas for me to at least try or other solutions. (Sorry if that seemed passive-aggressive, I appreciate you giving up your time to help me)

Comment: To rule out the caching problem mentioned by @Blunder create a new texture and bake to that new texture. If it bakes, but not properly, it's not caching problem.

Comment: maybe pack your image and share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Do you bake on CPU or GPU? Have you tried a simple scene like the default cube? I've just noticed that your baked background is transparent. This is strange. There are 2 similar questions: [Why my normal map baking go white transparent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227494/why-my-normal-map-baking-go-white-transparent) (no answer) and [Normal map bakes with transparent areas](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/227285/normal-map-bakes-with-transparent-areas) (HDD/SDD issue, fixed it)